# FlyWay .... Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, flyway

I have two Java/Maven projects being developed under Intellij.

The first project is a simple java database app that uses, among others, FlyWay to manage the schema. It works fine!!

I start a second project, database app again but with different purpose, ie *.java files a different, but for all intents and purpose the intellij environment is the same ... POMs almost identical ... and it passes all tests and inspections ..

HOWEVER, when i ask FlyWay to maintain the schema i get

> Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration

It is driving me nuts because and i cannot find any other forum posts on it ... (clearly it is ME!!)

Has anybody got some ideas about how i might solve this?? :)

Thanks in advance.

PS: How does one post POM here without making a right mess???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.zimpics.eds.wa
    excel-report-format-application
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    
        
            
                
                org.apache.maven.plugins
                maven-compiler-plugin
                3.8.0
                
                    7
                    7
                
            
        
    
     
        UTF-8
        2016
        Emu Data Services
        http://www.emudataservices.com
    
      
        
        
            org.apache.maven.plugins
            maven-compiler-plugin
            3.8.0
        
        
            com.h2database
            h2
            1.4.197
        
        
        
            org.xerial
            sqlite-jdbc
            3.25.2
        
       
            org.apache.poi
            poi
            3.17
        
        
            org.apache.poi
            poi-ooxml
            3.17
        
        
        
            org.apache.commons
            commons-dbcp2
            2.5.0
        
        
        
            org.flywaydb
            flyway-core
            5.1.4
        
        
        
            org.slf4j
            slf4j-log4j12
            1.7.25
        
        
            org.slf4j
            jcl-over-slf4j
            1.7.25
        
        
        
            junit
            junit
            4.12
            test

Comment: After updating flyway to a newer version I had to add a slash: `classpath:/db/migration`

Comment: thanks Stephen! ... and if i may show my ignorance, just where does one make this change?